# Extracting a specific portion of a string with regex

Tags: jquery-ui

```
javascript:checkForSave('./viewSectorDefPage.htm');,viewSectorDefPage,htm');
```

from this string I want to extract only the value of `viewSectorDefPage` portion by regex, I have tried multiple examples but could not get it, any help will be appriciable,

Answer (score 0):

First attempt:

```
result = "javascript:checkForSave('./viewSectorDefPage.htm');,viewSectorDefPage,htm');".match(",(.*),")
```

this gives you the solution in `result[1]`